# Get total count of rows in ORACLE and then get only 4 results

Tags: sql, oracle

I am building a search engine, therefore, as in google, I am displaying only 4 results but I also need the total number of matched results.
Can I do in a single query in ORACLE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select *
from (
  select col1, 
         col2,
         row_number() over (order by some_column) as rn,
         count(*) over () as total_count
  from the_table
) 
where rn <= 4;
```

But if that table is really big, it is not going to be very fast.

Comment: Top-n is available from 12c :-)

Comment: It is throwing ORA_00937: not a single group-group function.

Comment: @ghufranne: I had a typo in my first version. You need to use `count(*) over ()` not a plain `count(*)`

Comment: Thanks its working, but why are we using row_number() instead we can use rownum? does row_number() give better performance?

Comment: @ghufranne: because `row_number()` is more flexible and gives more control on how the numbers are created. [quote from the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns009.htm): "*The ROW_NUMBER built-in SQL function provides superior support for ordering the results of a query*"

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below;

ready to run query:

```
        SELECT tbl2.*
  FROM (SELECT tbl1.*, ROWNUM rownumber
          FROM (SELECT 1, 2, count(*) FROM DUAL) tbl1) tbl2
 WHERE tbl2.rownumber BETWEEN 0 AND 4;
```

And the result is:

```
column1|column2|COUNT(*)|ROWNUMBER
   1        2       1       1
```

This gets the rows between 0 and 4. So if you want to get others, you can modify to get inputs for those values instead.

Answer (score 1):

From 12c, you can avoid the `RANK` method, and use the `TOP-N` query directly :

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM
  3    ( SELECT object_name,
  4      COUNT(*) OVER () AS total_count FROM all_objects
  5    )
  6  FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
  7  /

OBJECT_NAME TOTAL_COUNT
----------- -----------
I_OBJ1            89738
CLU$              89738
I_COL3            89738
I_UNDO1           89738
I_CDEF4           89738

SQL>
```

Comment: Nope. In 10g you are bound to use the windowing function.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be using a single SQL statement, but check out the APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT() function, which is designed to be a very quick approximate COUNT for use in things like search engines where the exact number of results may not be essential.

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NEWFT/chapter12102.htm#BGBJEAJE