# Oracle select * and rownum

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Im trying to select all values from a table + adding rownum for every row after ordering it alphabetically. (Using java, this is the query)

```
Select * FROM
  (Select *, rownum as row_id from
          (Select * FROM emp ORDER BY ename))
                Where row_id>=((?-1)*?)+1 and row_id<=(?*?);
```

However im getting

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

And I believe its because `Select *, rownum as row_id from` what's the correct way of selecting all fields and adding new ones ?

Comment: Correct, * can't be mixed with anything else. table.* may however help you!

Comment: Please see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338007/get-total-count-of-rows-in-oracle-and-then-get-only-4-results/26338583#26338583).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `*` (in Oracle) with any other columns, you need to qualify it.  So, try this:

```
Select e.*
FROM (Select e.*, rownum as row_id
      from (Select *
            FROM emp
            ORDER BY ename
           ) e
     ) e
Where row_id >= ((?-1)*?)+1 and row_id <= (?*?);
```